Can one utilize the Curry-Howard correspondence, or some analogue result, for optimizations?
I have not studied this topic at length, but as I understand it, this correspondence is an isomorphism between computer programs and mathematical proofs. Thinking about this, isn't it possible to convert a program into a proof with several propositions and then use the Karnaugh–Veitch map algorithm, or the Quine–McCluskey algorithm, to reduce the boolean logical expressions to their optimal form, and then use the Curry-Howard isomorphism again to get an "logically" optimized program, that is to say, the algorithmical implementations would have the least amount of steps making them optimized in the sense of using the least amount of CPU instructions (of course, a very large part of computer program optimization has to do with trying the best to avoid cache misses, and parallelism and other hardware considerations so as to get the fastest programs), but being able to transform a program into a shorter (in the sense of instructions) equivalent program may be a first step into a general optimization procedure.
I know that in lambda calculus there is a process called $\beta$-reduction that can simplify functional expressions by incomplete (or possibly complete) evaluations, but when studing the Haskell programming language, there was a passage saying that $\beta$-reduction is not guaranteed to produce the most logically optimized expression.
Basically I was interested in any method or result pertaining to a mathematical theory of program optimiztion, but I don't seem to find any books on the topic (partially because searching for "mathematical" toghether with "optimization" usually results in books about maximazing or minimizing the output of some real function, like it is done in a calculus book).

In order to apply Curry-Howard to program optimisation, we would have to have an already well-developed theory of "proof optimisation". No such thing exists, because of course mathematicians don't care about how many steps their proofs take (to wit: most of them still use ZFC as foundations!). So it's unclear what you're after.

The problem is that when you don't have ZFC several theorems that have important ramifications, appear to be devoid of proof, or the ones that are equivalent to it, to begin with. But, as I understand, there is at least some exploration of a mathematical programming theory in the form of those concepts such as Kolmogorov complexity, and some others in information theory, so I always thought that there ought to be some mathematically oriented programming optimization book, but, yes, I never found such a thing.

As a program, or part of it, is an algorithm, did you search for "algorithm" toghether with "optimization"?
